# Symfony2/Twig/Bootstrap: How to customize DeleteForm Button

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I have Twig Template: show.html.twig.

In it there is an Delete Button in a bootstrap form Group. I want to style the button like the other in the Form Group but it doesnt work, here is my code:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <a href="{{ path('secure_mail') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Back</a>
        {{ form_widget(delete_form.submit, { 'label': 'Delete' }, { 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-default', 'type' => 'button'} }) }}
    </div>
```

Isn't it possible to design this button?

Comment: Can't really answer this for you as we can't see what "design" you're trying to compare to, but you have `{ 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-default'}` declared, just change the class selectors in this to the ones you are using for styling in CSS?

Comment: The "BACK" Button which is in first position in my button-group has the correct design! Now I want the DELETE Button in the same Design like the Back-Button. So I gave it the same class and type. But the Delete Button doesnt look like the first one! It doenst take the class and type!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
{{ form_widget(delete_form.submit, { 'label': 'Delete' }, { 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-default', 'type' => 'button'} }) }}
```

To:

```
{{ form_widget(delete_form.submit,{ 'label': 'Delete' }, { 'attr': {'class': 'myOwnClassSelectorsHere', 'type': 'button'} }) }}
```

Use your CSS selectors inside the `attr` declaration and it will use any styles you have applied to that class.

Where `{ 'attr': {'class': '...', 'type' : 'button'}` is defined, that is how the styling is being applied. It is using `btn btn-default` as the styling selectors from Twitter Bootstrap.

The reason you're not seeing any changes is because you have `=>` declared instead of `:`.

For the label, try:

```
{{ form_widget(delete_form.submit,{ 'label': 'Delete' }, { 'attr': {'class': 'myOwnClassSelectorsHere', 'type': 'button'} }) }}
```

Comment: THATS IT!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH! REALLY COOL! And it is now possible to set an own label anywhere?

Comment: @Zwen2012, do you mean the text to appear inside the button?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean!